# Knockout: How to Change Data for Same Model depending on Some condition

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, frontend

I have a Table where in Data comes dynamically depending on some condition. I wish to some data For example on click of button.

```
    if(true){
       Show: ABC Data
}
       else{
        Show XYZ Data
        }
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qWmat/8/)  I used to expand my functionality but unfortunately I am stuck on this requirement.

Comment: I don't understand what it is that has to happen depending on the condition. Render a different view? Bind the inputs to a different item? Can you elaborate (in the context of your fiddle)?

Comment: @user3297291 Sure, So If you see the output in Fiidle, there is an Table with predefined Value. For our simple Case I wish to have a Button at Bottm let's call it change Table Value and clicking on it, Shall change the Value, Here is the New [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AnkUser/tq4zaxpu/3/) with Button

Answer (score 1):

In your viewmodel constructor, you've defined some logic on how to load data:

```
self.items = ko.observableArray(data.map(function(i) {
  return new rowModel(i.id, i.name, i.status);
}));
```

Because `items` is an observable array, you're free to update its contents whenever you like!

Let's move the mapping logic to a separate function:

```
self.loadData = function(rawData) {
  var viewmodels = rawData.map(function(d) {
    return new RowModel(d.id, d.name, d.status);
  });

  self.items(viewmodels);
};
```

In your constructor, you can now load the initial data like so:

```
self.items = ko.observableArray();
self.loadData(data);
```

In the `click` callback of your button, you'll reuse our new `loadData` method:

```
self.changeTableData = function() {
  if (someCondition()) {
    self.loadData([ /* ... */ ]);
  } else {
    self.loadData([ /* ... */ ]);
  }
}
```

---

Optional:

For purely aesthetic reasons, I usually define a static constructor helper for easy mapping:

```
RowModel.fromRawDataPoint = function(dataPoint) {
  return new RowModel(dataPoint.id, dataPoint.name, dataPoint.status);
};
```

I'd move the functions defined in the constructor to the VM's prototype:

```
MyVM.prototype.loadData = function(rawData) {
  this.items(rawData.map(RowModel.fromRawDataPoint));
};
```

Here's an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/975ncawv/

Comment: Yes this is exactly I wished to achieve. Thanks for the input and explanation.